# Encoding video using Vp8 encoding scheme

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hi I want to encode raw(**yuv**) video to **m4v** using ffmpeg command in **Vp8** encoding scheme, i try to use this command:

```
./ffmpeg -s 1280x720 -i raw.yuv -vcodec libvpx 1.m4v
```

but the error was :

```
    Input #0, rawvideo,from 'raw.yuv':
  Duration: 00:00:58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 276416 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: raw, yuv420p, 1280x720, 276480Kbs,25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp4 @ 0x13acff0]track 1: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in c
ontainer
Output #0, ipod, to '1.m4v':
metadata:
encoder :lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0.0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 676x380, q=1--1, 200k,90k tbn, 25
tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0(raw video ->libvpx)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
```

Please I need a help.

Answer (score 4):

M4V is a renamed MP4 container, and so it can only contain MPEG codecs (and a small number of non-MPEG audio codecs, like AC3). VP8 is not an MPEG codec. You have to put it in an MKV or WEBM (actually a deliberately-limited form of MKV) container.

```
ffmpeg -s 1280x720 -i raw.yuv -c:v libvpx output.webm
```

If you wish achieve good results with VP8, you should read the [VP8 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide) on the [FFmpeg wiki](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki).

Comment: @evilsoup :I want to ask you when i executed your command i got the output file, but I want to encapsulate this video using mp4box into m4v. But  the error is : unknown input file type 1.mkv

Comment: You can't put VP8 video in an MP4 with any tool. It is impossible: MP4 is only able to contain a small range of codecs, and VP8 is not one of them. Use H.264 video instead, if you want it in an MP4 (see the [x264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)).

Comment: @evilsoup: Thanks for your response, but i want it in VP8 , i'm already did it in H.264. Is there any way to encapsulate VP8 video??

Comment: Not in an MP4, no. You have to use MKV or WEBM. Why would you want VP8 in an MP4 container, anyway?

Comment: @evilsoup: I want to encapsulate(hint track) the webm video(raw yuv) how can i do that?

Comment: @Computer_Engineer Hint tracks are specific to ISO base media file formats and RTP streaming – such a thing does not exist for the WebM format. Maybe if you explained more about what your actual requirement is, somebody could help you get a better gist of the whole thing?

Comment: @slhck: I want to evaluate Vp8 video using Evalvid framework, but evalvid contains mp4box and mp4trace and these don't deal with Webm or mkv video, What are the alternatives for mp4box to hint track webm video?

Comment: @Computer_Engineer First of all, Evalvid does not support VP8/WebM video, and there's no such thing as "hint tracks" for WebM. Those are specific to (mostly) MPEG containers. Streaming WebM over RTP is still a little experimental and currently [just a proposal](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-payload-vp8-08) at the IETF.